# Add end date to record that is the start date of the next record (linq to sql)

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql

An address table has 1 or more addresses per type and  employee. Each row has an address effective date, but no end date. I need to "fake" an end date by using the employees next address effective date.

The source table is:

```
EFFDT       ADDRESS1          ADDRESS_TYPE  EMPLID
12/21/1999  7927 SW 31st Ave    HOME          6
4/15/2002   7070  Shady Lane    HOME          6
3/18/2014   1228 Hall           HOME          6
```

The result should be:

```
EFFDT       ADDRESS1          ADDRESS_TYPE  EMPLID    ENDDATE
12/21/1999  7927 SW 31st Ave    HOME          6      4/15/2002
4/15/2002   7070  Shady Lane    HOME          6      3/18/2014 
3/18/2014   1228 Hall           HOME          6       NULL
```

My SQL works, but getting it to work in Linq to SQL has been and issue. I'm not certain if the SQL is the best, because it's not taking type into account. But currently, all my data has only HOME type addresses. Id like to account for other types as well.
Here is the SQL:

```
Select A.EFFDT, A.ADDRESS1, A.ADDRESS_TYPE, A.EMPLID,
(SELECT MIN(EFFDT) 
    FROM dbo.PS_ADDRESSES 
    WHERE EFFDT > A.EFFDT AND EMPLID = A.EMPLID) as EndDate
FROM dbo.PS_ADDRESSES A 
ORDER BY A.EMPLID
```

Comment: You should show your attempt at translating it to Linq so that people can point out what's wrong and correct your mistakes.

Comment: For the type you just need to add the `ADDRESS_TYPE = A.ADDRESS_TYPE` comparison to the where clause of the sub-query.

Comment: Yes @Mat, but I felt where I was going with the solution was too far off, and would cause the question to go off track.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The translation is easy, though I didn't try to optimize the LINQ (perhaps a group by would be more efficient).

```
from a in dbo.PS_ADDRESSES
orderby a.EMPLID
select new {
    a.EFFDT, a.ADDRESS, a.ADDRESS_TYPE, a.EMPLID,
    EndDate = (from na in dbo.PS_ADDRESSES where na.EFFDT > a.EFFDT && na.ADDRESS_TYPE == a.ADDRESS_TYPE && na.EMPLID == a.EMPLID select na.EFFDT).Min()
```

}

When translating, just translate the clauses in LINQ order: `from`, `where`, [`orderby`], `select` and realize that `MIN`, `MAX`, `DISTINCT` and `TOP` are done as postfix functions. The LINQ comprehension syntax authors made the decision not to include any unary lambda functions in the syntax. It helps if the SQL already has a table alias in the `FROM` to match LINQ syntax, but you can always add one (as I did with `na`).